# Android: When is WakeLock needed?

Tags: android

If I have an IntentService that simply updates the `SharedPreference`, is a (partial) `WakeLock` needed?

I understand that a `WakeLock` keeps the **CPU** awake, but when is it needed?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep the CPU running in order to complete some work before the device goes to sleep, you can use a PowerManager system service feature called wake locks. Wake locks allow your application to control the power state of the host device.

Creating and holding wake locks can have a dramatic impact on the host device's battery life. Thus you should use wake locks only when strictly necessary and hold them for as short a time as possible. For example, you should never need to use a wake lock in an activity.

One legitimate case for using a wake lock might be a background service that needs to grab a wake lock to keep the CPU running to do work while the screen is off. Again, though, this practice should be minimized because of its impact on battery life.

Unfortunately, some poorly-coded, malicious, or simply buggy apps might create an abnormal amount of undesirable wakelocks. Other apps require constant Internet access in order to operate in a normal fashion - Facebook and Messenger are probably the most popular representatives. They persistently request information from the web (the so-called "polling" for new events), which is causing subsequent wakelocks.

In other cases, an update to a given app can also cause certain issues, which usually result in partial wakelocks. The latter keep your CPU constantly humming in the background, sometimes without your knowledge, and prevent your device from "going to sleep". That's a pretty substantial prerequisite for anomalous battery drain. Thus, it is advisable to regularly monitor the wakelocks on your device and see which of your apps go harsh on our system's resources.

Read more at:

[What-are-wakelocks-how-they-affect-the-battery-life-of-your-Android-device-and-how-to-Greenify](http://www.phonearena.com/news/What-are-wakelocks-how-they-affect-the-battery-life-of-your-Android-device-and-how-to-Greenify-them_id58739#IV7iVjvUpBFUJrBH.99)

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: So is it a yes or no regarding my first question?

Comment: As noted in the answer - "If you need to keep the CPU running in order to complete some work before the device goes to sleep, you can use wake locks." Updating a shared preference doesn't necessarily implies the statement unless you really want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It is needed when you don't want CPU to sleep when user locks the screen for example.

If you have an `IntentService` without acquired `WakeLock` it will pause after a while if user locks the screen and it will continue its work when user wakes a device. With `WakeLock` acquired your service will work even if the screen is locked.

As @My God mentioned, it impacts on battery life a lot, so, use it only when you really need to finish some operation and you cannot wait till user wakes a device.

Comment: But if I run an `IntentService` without acquiring a wake lock, I never actually see it stopping. It just keeps running and handles every single intent one after another.

Comment: It is possible that something else is keeping your CPU awake. It's not supposed to be always awake because it means the battery is drained much faster than it should be. Having a wake lock is not a requirement but something to be aware of. If you are doing some sensitive operations then it's safer to acquire the lock. If it's ok to postpone the operations until the CPU wakes up, then go with this approach instead. The last one is the preferred way, in most cases the wake lock is not needed.